# use special characters in sed in variable

Tags: unix, sed, symbols

I have a requirement like

```
cat File
cd-car~1~3
```

I want to replace cd-car with $string1 I used the below code

```
$string1=cd-p&c
sed -i "s/cd-car~/$string1~/g' File
```

I am getting the following output

```
cat File
~1~3
```

Please help me out

Comment: Would you like to replace `cd-car` with the string `$string1`, or the value in the variable `$string1`

Comment: @jotne I wish to $string1 is the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote `cd-p&c`. Otherwise, `c` command is executed; and nothing is set to `string1` variable.

```
$ string1=cd-p&c
[1] 6137
c: command not found
[1]+  Done                    string1=cd-p
$ echo $string1

$
```

The `&` character is special in the replacement part of sed's `s///` command: it is replaced by the text that matched the pattern. If you want a literal `&` you have to escape it,

```
$ string1='cd-p\&d'
$ echo $string1
cd-p&d
$ sed -i "s/cd-car~/$string1~/g" File
$ cat File
cd-p&c~1~3
```

Comment: still getting the same output

Comment: I am getting the output as cd-pcd-car~c~1~2

Comment: I am able to get the desired output using the below code

     $ string1='cd-p\&c'
     $ echo $string1
     cd-p&d
     $ sed -i "s/cd-car~/$string1~/g" File
     $ cat File
     cd-p&c~1~3

Thank you guys for the reply

Comment: The `&` character is special in the replacement part of sed's `s///` command: it is replaced by the text that matched the pattern. If you want a literal `&` you have to escape it, as you discovered.

Comment: @glennjackman, Thank you for comment. I update the answer with your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`

```
awk '{sub(/cd-car/,"$string1")}1' file
$string1~1~3
```